# A sufficient condition for a distribution to be temperate

Tags: schwartz-distributions

Claim: Let $T$ be a distribution on $\mathbb R^n$ such that $\nabla T$ belongs to $L^p(\mathbb R^n)$ for some $p\in [1,+\infty]$. Then $T$ is a temperate distribution,
i.e. belongs to the topological dual of the Schwartz class $\mathscr S(\mathbb R^n)$.

I believe that the previous claim holds true, but I do not have a complete proof.

Comment: Much more is true. If I remember it right, once $\nabla T$ is a temperate distribution and $T$ is a distribution, you can immediately conclude that $T$ is temperate as well. Try to look it up in Hormander. If you fail, I'll post the proof.

Answer (score 3):

Let's do it in dimension $1$. 
 By Holder's inequality 
$$\int_0^x|f'(x)|dx\leq \| f'\|_p|x|^{1-1/p}.$$
A distribution with locally integrable derivative is a continuous function,
$$f(x)=f(0)+\int_0^xf'(x)dx=O(|x|^{1-1/p}),\quad x\to\infty.$$
Thus
$$(f,\phi)=\int f\phi$$
is absolutely convergent and defines a bounded linear functional on $\mathscr S$, that is a tempered distribution. For higher dimension the proof is essentially the same.

Comment: Thanks for the 1 D argument. You write that the same argument works in $n$ dimensions, which is not absolutely clear to me since the representation of $f$ via $\nabla f$ cannot obviously be used in the same way.